# dictionary to JSON?

Tags: javascript, python, json, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
terms = {"Taste Term":{'children': ['Receptor', 'Descriptor', 'Modulator', 'Tissue'], 'parent': []},"Receptor":{'children': ['ion channel'], 'parent': ['Taste Term']}, "Descriptor":{'children': [], 'parent': ['Taste Term']}, "Modulator":{'children': [], 'parent': ['Taste Term']},"Tissue":{'children': [], 'parent': ['Taste Term']}}
```

when I dump this dictionary with `print json.dumps(terms, indent=4)`
i get the following Json file:

```
{
"Descriptor": {
    "children": [], 
    "parent": [
        "Taste Term"
    ]
}, 
"Tissue": {
    "children": [], 
    "parent": [
        "Taste Term"
    ]
}, 
"Receptor": {
    "children": [
        "ion channel"
    ], 
    "parent": [
        "Taste Term"
    ]
}, 
"Modulator": {
    "children": [], 
    "parent": [
        "Taste Term"
    ]
}, 
"Taste Term": {
    "children": [
        "Receptor", 
        "Descriptor", 
        "Modulator", 
        "Tissue"
    ], 
    "parent": []
}
}
```

the json file i want looks like this:

```
{
"name":"Taste Term",
"children": [
 {
  "name":"Receptor",
  "children": [

     {"name":"ion channel"}
   ]
  },
  {"name":"Descriptor"},
  {"name":"Modulator"},
  {"name":"Tissue"}
 ]
 }
```

Now, How can I edit my dictionary to get to the correct structure for Json to output the lower Json file? So I need to edit the dictionary `terms` in such a way that the children have the children in them.

Comment: First worry about how to transform the dict into the other dict. The "converting to JSON" part is trivial, and not really relevant to the problem.

Comment: Hi, you recommend transforming this dictionary to another dictionary with a different layout? A layout that can be directly dumped?

Comment: @Henkes: yes. The `json` library produces valid JSON as a one-on-one translation of the Python dictionary, list and value structure. You need to do the transformation first.

Comment: What do you already tried ? I clearly see what you have, what you try to get, but I can't figure what you already tried to help you to do it better...

Comment: edited my question, The children's children is what I'm struggeling with. (and their children etc.)

Comment: it is still unclear what problems you have.

Comment: @Alik Where I'm at right now is making some kind of loop which adds the childrens children. I can print the root node with it's children but I have not managed to add the grandchildren etc.

Comment: Can you update the question with your current approach/current state of development? It's not really clear how you are currently trying to solve the problem and where exactly the your code is not working properly.

Comment: @p9teufel question updated with better information. I hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often the simplest way to deal with recursive data structures is by using a recursive function. In this case it's possible to write one that transforms the "nodes" in the flat dictionary you have into the kind needed for the nested dictionary structure you want. Once this is done you can just `json.dumps()` the result to get it into JSON format.

In the code below I've corrected the syntax of the starting `terms` dictionary provided in your question and reformatted it to clearly show its structure.

```
import json

terms = {
     'root':      {'p': [],          'c': ['branch1', 'branch2', 'branch3']},
     'branch1':   {'p': ['root'],    'c': ['branch1.1']},
     'branch2':   {'p': ['root'],    'c': []},
     'branch3':   {'p': ['root'],    'c': []},
     'branch1.1': {'p': ['branch1'], 'c': []}
}

def transform(d, parent):
    return (
        {'name': parent}
            if not d[parent]['c'] else
        {'name': parent,
         'children': [transform(d, child) for child in d[parent]['c']]}
    )

print(json.dumps(transform(terms, 'root'), indent=2))
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "branch1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "branch1.1"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "branch2"
    },
    {
      "name": "branch3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks the recursive transform function is exactly what I needed! With regular for loops it didn't work.

Comment: It's possible to do it without recursion, however doing so requires an auxiliary data structure like a stack or queue to keep track of things, so is often more complicated. Recursion effectively replaces that with the program's own function call stack.

Comment: my question is how to go go about the build the terms dictionary to begin with? Any link to relevant API or other resources would be great. thanks!

Comment: @HR123r: One very flexible way is by something called "[autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification)". More generally, look up things related to building the data-structure known as a "[Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_structure)". They can also be represented as nested sequences.

Comment: @martineau: Thank you, I looked up autovivification in python, the point I am missing is that in autovivification is like dictionary of dicts, here it's a dictionary of dictionaries with lists as the values. How about this exact format, how do we reach it. Thank you

Comment: Although there's only  one dictionary here, it contains the nodes of the whole Tree, which are represented with id strings here — so it's equivalent to a dictionary of dictionaries. That means it should be possible to convert one into the other. Therefor, I think, that you can think about and do things with whichever representation is the most convenient for you (and convert it the other as needed). If I run across and good example or reference like you want, I'll let you know.

Comment: @martineau: Thank you! I see that it's dict of dicts but the 'p' and 'c' have lists right?

Comment: Yes — I misspoke. It's a dict of dicts, but the physical nesting never goes any deeper (so it'll never become a dict of dicts of dicts of ...etc) but logically it can represent that.

Comment: I guess you could think of it as a Tree representation using pointers (the node id strings).

Comment: @martineau  I have been looking a lot around the internet, and I can't seem to find an example on how to build the terms dictionary. Do you thin you can post a tutorial for it, or change your answer to incorporate that? It would be really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @HR123r: Don't think that's a good idea since it has little to do with this question. Suggest you try taking the output produced here and reverse-transforming it back into the original structure. Then, if you can't figure that out, post a separate question here on SO describing what you want to do and showing your attempt.